# geoJson stroke overlap on hover

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, qgis

I am creating a MapBox project with a geoJson vector layer.  I have been using the following example as my guide.

https://www.mapbox.com/blog/neighborhood-mapping-with-dynamic-vector-data-layers/

When I hover over any geoJson feature the stroke is changed to 2 pixels.  However the stroke gets clipped by the neighboring features sometimes.  I believe this has something to do with how the different features are stacked.  So if I hover on a feature which is stacked near the bottom the neighboring features are covering that stroke.

Here is an example...
http://www.vandam.com/chpc/inconsistent_stroke.jpg

Is their a way to set the stroke to be inside of the polygon or a way to bring a feature to  the top of the stack when hovering?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

By adding the function

layer.bringtoFront();

after setting the hover styling your polygons will come to front.